# Unity - Lag happen only when i first intantiate an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a detection script that look like this:

```
IEnumerator Detect()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var collision = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, radius, layerMask);

            if (collision != null)
            {
                var obj = collision.GetComponent<IDetectionObject>();

                if (lastDetectedObject != obj)
                {
                    obj.Ping();
                    lastDetectedObject = obj;
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
        }
    }
```

And this script will trigger (ping) a dialogue banter, and will deliver the banter to the player. and player will run this code:

```
public void Say(string banter, float duration)
{
    currentBubble = bubbleManager.GetBubble();

    currentBubble.SetText(banter);
    currentBubble.BindToTransform(transform, () => currentBubble = null);
    currentBubble.SetDuration(duration);
}
```

The BubbleManager.cs Script using a PoolObject from unity, this is the code:

```
private void Awake()
{
    bubblePool = new ObjectPool<BanterBubble>(() =>
    {
        return Instantiate(bubblePrefab, transform);
    }, bubble =>
    {
        bubble.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }, bubble =>
    {
        bubble.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }, bubble =>
    {
        Destroy(bubble);
    }, false, 10, 20);
}

public BanterBubble GetBubble()
{
    var bubble = bubblePool.Get();
    bubble.Init(this);
    return bubble;
}

public void ReleaseBubble(BanterBubble bubble)
{
    bubblePool.Release(bubble);
}
```

Okay, now here is the problem. Whenever i test play my game, and when player detect IDetectionObject interface, its always lag. but only for the first time.

and after that the game will run smoothly, even though i trigger so many IDetectionObjects. the lag is pretty bad so i really want to clear this problem.

**What I Already Done**

- Use Instantiate() instead of Get Object from PoolObject which is BubbleManager, the lag still happen on the first time. after that always smooth.
- Build the game and play. And yes.. the lag still happen in build game.
- Use Debug. and yes the lag is gone. so i think the problem is with how i instantiate my object

**What I Suspect**

- The Bubble is a UI object, so it must use a canvas to render, maybe instantiating a canvas object is heavy?
- Maybe My Unity Version is not stable ? I use Unity 2022.1.10f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element changed in canvas, the whole canvas rebuild.

"Many users build their entire game’s UI on a single Canvas with thousands of elements. When they change one element, they can experience a CPU spike costing multiple milliseconds" from unity [docs](https://unity.com/how-to/unity-ui-optimization-tips#split-your-canvases).

Comment: Oh my... Thank you.. i'll search another way to instantiate then